# PHP JSON Retrieve Object Values

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get all objects from the .json file. With the `stylers` object, I want to get the only item in it. I cannot get `color` or `visibility`

file.json

```
[

  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "red" }
    ]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }, {
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" }

    ]
  }

]
```

PHP code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('file.json');
$arr = json_decode($json);

foreach($arr as $o) {

    echo $o->featureType;  //Works fine
    echo $o->elementType;  //Works fine

    foreach ($o->stylers as $key => $value) {

        echo $value;  //This doesn't get the color or visibility
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$value` is an `stdClass` object. So, to call `color` or `visibility` you need:

```
echo $value->color;
```

```
echo $value->visibility;
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I know the key names? Sometimes it won't have a color and `$value->color` will produce an error.

Comment: You can get all the propriety names with `get_object_vars($value)`. Check with `isset($value->color)` if it exists.